# Select colour of boxplot based on function in R

Tags: r, colors, plot, boxplot

I am plotting boxplots of fish biomass by reefname, in order of median biomass. All reefnames (sites) are either in or out of a `MPA`, e.g `MPA="1"` or `MPA=="0"`. Currently all plots show green.

How can I show `MPA=="0"` sites as blue and `MPA=="1"` as green for example. While maintaining the order of the fish biomass.

```
MPA <- factor(Fish$MPA)
bymedian <- with(Fish, reorder(ReefName, log10(Biomassm+1)), median)
boxplot(log10(Biomassm+1) ~ bymedian, data = Fish,
        xlab = "ReefName", ylab = "Biomassm",
        main = "Biomassm in Caribbean", varwidth = TRUE, 
        col=(c("darkgreen")), las=3, cex.axis=0.3)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It might be a better idea to use the `ggplot2` package for this. Your code would then look like this:

```
ggplot(data=Fish, aes(x=reorder(ReefName, log10(Biomassm+1)), median), y=Biomassm, fill=MPA)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_y_log10("Biomassm") +
  xlab("ReefName") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "green")) +
  ggtitle("Biomassm in Caribbean")
```

Comment: Error in data.frame(x = c(44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 22L,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 326, 0

Comment: Can you include a `dput` of you dataframe in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a set of boxplots coloured depending on the value of MPA:

```
# generate some data
set.seed(1)
X = matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)

# order by median
X = X[,order(apply(X, 2, median))]

# some fake MPA values  
MPA = round(runif(n=10, min=0, max=1))

# generate boxplots and check if MPA==1
boxplot(X, col=ifelse(test=MPA==1, yes='green', no='blue'))

# add legend
legend(x='bottomleft', fill=c('green','blue'), legend=c('MPA=1', 'MPA=0'), inset=c(0.01))
```

The output of `ifelse` is a vector of colours according to the MPA values and these are used to colour the boxes:

```
[1] "blue"  "blue"  "green" "blue"  "blue"  "green" "green" "blue"  "blue"  "green"
```

[image: coloured boxplots]